# How to create custom message in C#?

Tags: c#

I am design a custom message box. This message box will show a list of string. But it's not work. Can you hep me to fix it. 
You can see in the picture, I have a list with 7 items. When i click the "Grade Project", the Message box don't show any item.
[image]
And this is the result I need

[image]

```
//Main form
 private void btnGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            result.Add("True");
            result.Add("False");
            result.Add("True");
            result.Add("False");
            result.Add("True");
            result.Add("False");
            result.Add("False");
            MsgBox.Show(result,"Project 1",MsgBox.Buttons.OK);
        }
```

This is code in msgbox form

```
//MsgBox form
    public partial class MsgBox : Form
    {
       private static MsgBox _msgBox;

        // Header, Footer 
        private Panel _plHeader = new Panel();
        private Label _lblTitle;
        private Panel _plFooter = new Panel();
        private Panel _plIcon = new Panel();
        // Panel
        private FlowLayoutPanel _flpButtons = new FlowLayoutPanel();

        // button
        private List<Button> _buttonCollection = new List<Button>();

        // Kết quả
        private static DialogResult _buttonResult;
        // Message
        private List<String> _lblMessage;

        private MsgBox()
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 48);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.Width = 800;

            // Header
            _lblTitle = new Label();
            _lblTitle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            _lblTitle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 18);
            _lblTitle.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            _lblTitle.Height = 60;

            // Message
            _lblMessage = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < _lblMessage.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox(); //Create Textbox có name txt
                txt.Text = _lblMessage[i];
                txt.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                txt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 30);
                this.Controls.Add(txt);  //add control txt
            }

            _flpButtons.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            _flpButtons.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            _plHeader.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            _plHeader.Padding = new Padding(20);
          //  _plHeader.Controls.Add(_lblMessage);
            _plHeader.Controls.Add(_lblTitle);

            _plFooter.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            _plFooter.Padding = new Padding(20);
            _plFooter.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(37, 37, 38);
            _plFooter.Height = 80;
            _plFooter.Controls.Add(_flpButtons);                       

            // Add controls vào form
            this.Controls.Add(_plHeader);
            //this.Controls.Add(_plIcon);
            this.Controls.Add(_plFooter);

        }
        public static DialogResult Show(List<String> message, string title, Buttons buttons)
        {
            _msgBox = new MsgBox();
            _msgBox._lblMessage = message;
            _msgBox._lblTitle.Text = title;
            _msgBox._plIcon.Hide();
            MsgBox.InitButtons(buttons);
            _msgBox.ShowDialog();          
            return _buttonResult;
        }
```

Thank you for your watching.

Comment: `"Result " + string.Join(" ", result)`

Comment: Your idea is very clever. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something wrong with your codes:

```
private MsgBox()
{
    ...
    // Message
    _lblMessage = new List<string>();
    ...
}
```

Your _lblMessage will always be an empty list so you see no message at all.

You can change your codes like this:

```
private MsgBox(List<String> messages)
{
    ...
    // Message
    _lblMessage = messages;
    ...
}

public static DialogResult Show(List<String> message, string title)
{
    _msgBox = new MsgBox(message);
    //_msgBox._lblMessage = message;
    ....
}
```

And also, you'd better set TextBox position otherwise all the TextBox will overlap with each other.